# New component in python for Spring Boot

Tags: python, spring-boot

I have a legacy Spring Boot system and I need to create to a new component (restful service) in python for the system. However, I was not able to find a wrapper for Spring Boot in python.

So far I have the following ideas but they are not really efficient:

- Create the component as java class and execute the python script
- Deploy the python script as a RESTful service, create a component as java class and forward the request to the python service and return the result

Does anyone have any better idea how it is possible?

Thanks!